# WPF Storyboard requires TargetName

Tags: wpf, animation, storyboard

I have popup "Now playing" window in my app, and now I want to apply any cool effect to its show/hide. I don't want to create/dispose window each time I need to show/hide it, so I suppose I can't use `Window.Triggers`. I created sample storyboard and invoke it from code-behind; So it instantly fall into exception `No target was specified for 'System.Windows.Media.Animation.DoubleAnimation`. I found [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/910488/wpf-storyboard-beginner-problem) and added `Storyboard.TargetName` attribute.

```
    <Window.Resources>
        <Storyboard x:Key="OpenAnimation">
            <DoubleAnimation Storyboard.TargetName="NowPlaying" Storyboard.TargetProperty="(Window.Opacity)" Duration="0:0:5" From="0" To="1" />
        </Storyboard>
    </Window.Resources>
```

But it throws another exception: `Can't find name "NowPlaying" in namespace "VKPlaylist.GUI.NowPlaying".` But window code-behind class name IS `NowPlaying`. I also tried full name with namespace and it didn't change things.

How should I point proper name in this attribute? Is there any "magic" keyword like "this" so storyboard will know where to apply animation? I can't assign name attribute to window in XAML (and probably must not). It looks like dude in answer above easily solved his issue just by adding this attribute. What I am missing?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to set the `Name` attribute on your `<Window>` so that `TargetName` can reference it.

Comment: Oh wow. I wrote `I can't assign name attribute to window in XAML`, but I can. I just made a typo when tried to do it. Now animation works flawlessly. Thanks to point me a direction!