# Fading out a window

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, animation, window

I am currently developing a wpf c# application. I have added to event triggers to the xaml of the form to fade in when the window loads and fades out when the window closes.

The fading in works perfectly without any problems but the fading out is not working.

I have it set up so the window fades in when it loads, has a timer to last 5 seconds, and then calls the form fade out event.

However, the window doesn't fade out it just closes straight away no animation. Below is the code I have for the fade in and fade out events

```xml
<Window.Triggers>
        <EventTrigger RoutedEvent="Window.Loaded">
            <BeginStoryboard>
                <Storyboard Name="FormFade">
                    <DoubleAnimation Name="FormFadeAnimation"
                                     Storyboard.TargetProperty="(Window.Opacity)"
                                     From="0.0" To="1.0" Duration="0:0:1"
                                     AutoReverse="False" RepeatBehavior="1x" />
                </Storyboard>
            </BeginStoryboard>
        </EventTrigger>
        <EventTrigger RoutedEvent="Window.Unloaded">
            <BeginStoryboard>
                <Storyboard Name="FormFadeOut" Completed="FormFadeOut_Completed">
                    <DoubleAnimation Name="FormFadeOutAnimation"
                                     Storyboard.TargetName="FormFadeOut"
                                     Storyboard.TargetProperty="(Window.Opacity)"
                                     From="1.0" To="0.0" Duration="0:0:1"
                                     AutoReverse="False" RepeatBehavior="1x" />
                </Storyboard>
            </BeginStoryboard>
        </EventTrigger>
    </Window.Triggers>
```

Thanks for any help you can offer.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Fading out a wpf window on close](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/867656/fading-out-a-wpf-window-on-close)

Comment: Just a note to the above: Layered Windows `(WindowStyle=None, AllowsTransparency=True, Background=Transparent)` can be hardware rendered on Windows Vista or later and will avoid the black rectangular when its fading out.

Answer (score 40, accepted):

[Unloaded](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.frameworkelement.unloaded.aspx) is not a suitable event for this, i'm not sure if this event can even occur for windows. You need to handle `Closing`, prevent it from actually closing, start an animation and close it when the `Completed` event of the animation occurs.

e.g.

```xml
<Window ...
        Closing="Window_Closing">
```

```
private void Window_Closing(object sender, CancelEventArgs e)
{
    Closing -= Window_Closing;
    e.Cancel = true;
    var anim = new DoubleAnimation(0, (Duration)TimeSpan.FromSeconds(1));
    anim.Completed += (s, _) => this.Close();
    this.BeginAnimation(UIElement.OpacityProperty, anim);
}
```

Comment: I have tried what you have suggested and it is now coming up with an exception saying 'Window.Closing value cannot be assigned to property 'RoutedEvent of object System.Windows.EventTrigger

Comment: Can you see the code? This is **not** inside of the EventTriggers at all.

Comment: Sorry I misread your code, works perfectly, thanks for the help

Comment: You're welcome, but please take more care to look around on SO first next time as this question has a duplicate which should not have been hard to find.

Comment: Where to define Double Animation?

Comment: @Chris: I do not understand your question.

Comment: Solved my problem. DoubleAnimation is defined in `System.Windows.Media.Animation.DoubleAnimation`

Comment: This is perfect for me! is there an opposite of this to make a popup fad IN?

Comment: @TravisTubbs: You probably can set the opacity to 0 before opening the window/by default and then start an animation in `Loaded` in a similar way.

Answer (score 6):

just try this sample

```
<Window x:Class="FadeInAndOutWindow.Window1"
xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
Title="Window1" Height="300" Width="300" Closing="Window_Closing" x:Name="winHelp">
<Window.Triggers>
    <EventTrigger RoutedEvent="Window.Loaded">
        <BeginStoryboard>
            <Storyboard Name="FormFade">
                <DoubleAnimation  Name="FormFadeAnimation"
                                  Storyboard.TargetName="winHelp"
                                  Storyboard.TargetProperty="(Window.Opacity)"
                                  From="0.0"
                                  To="1.0"
                                  Duration="0:0:1"
                                  AutoReverse="False"
                                  RepeatBehavior="1x" />
            </Storyboard>
        </BeginStoryboard>
    </EventTrigger>
    <EventTrigger RoutedEvent="Window.Unloaded">
        <BeginStoryboard>
            <Storyboard Name="FormFadeOut"
                        Completed="FormFadeOut_Completed">
                <DoubleAnimation  Name="FormFadeOutAnimation"
                                  Storyboard.TargetName="winHelp"
                                  Storyboard.TargetProperty="(Window.Opacity)"
                                  From="1.0"
                                  To="0.0"
                                  Duration="0:0:1"
                                  AutoReverse="False"
                                  RepeatBehavior="1x" />
            </Storyboard>
        </BeginStoryboard>
    </EventTrigger>
</Window.Triggers>    
<Grid>

</Grid>
```

```
namespace FadeInAndOutWindow
{
    public partial class Window1 : Window
    {
        public Window1()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
        }

        private bool closeCompleted = false;


        private void FormFadeOut_Completed(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            closeCompleted = true;
            this.Close();
        }

        private void Window_Closing(object sender, System.ComponentModel.CancelEventArgs e)
        {

            if (!closeCompleted)
            {
                FormFadeOut.Begin();
                e.Cancel = true;
            }
        }

    }
}
```

Answer (score 5):

H.B. solution is good but don't close effectively the window because Close() call window_Closing and loop. Here my working solution:

```
    private void Window_Loaded(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        AlreadyFaded = false;
    }

    bool AlreadyFaded;
    private void window_Closing(object sender, CancelEventArgs e)
    {
        if (!AlreadyFaded)
        {
            AlreadyFaded = true;
            e.Cancel = true;
            var anim = new DoubleAnimation(0, (Duration)TimeSpan.FromSeconds(1));
            anim.Completed += new EventHandler(anim_Completed);
            this.BeginAnimation(UIElement.OpacityProperty, anim);
        }
    }

    void anim_Completed(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
         Close();
    }
```

Comment: This solution works great. I have created a BaseWindow class and all my windows inherit from it. All my windows have now this behaviour. Thank you for this improved version.

Comment: Works great, but for some reason it shows a black rectangular when its fading out.. any ideas on that?

Comment: The dialog must have AllowsTransparency="True" attribute to avoid the black rectangle.