# Window shown event in WPF?

Tags: c#, .net, wpf, xaml

I want to apply fade animation every time my window is shown. How to do that from xaml? That window can be hidden and then shown again so I can't use  `Loaded` event.

Comment: Look at this question, may be this will help:
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/867656/fading-out-a-wpf-window-on-close

Answer (score 59):

You can use the ContentRendered event or override OnContentRendered virtual method like this:

```
    bool _shown;

    protected override void OnContentRendered(EventArgs e)
    {
        base.OnContentRendered(e);

        if (_shown)
            return;

        _shown = true;

        // Your code here.
    }
```

Comment: Is it really needed to use _shown variable? Can rendered be called twice or more?

Comment: Yes, when your form shown twice or more. Mostly when form is child and needed to show and close again and again with 1 instance.

Answer (score 7):

You could use the

> IsVisibleChanged

Event from the WPF Window;

Then in the EventMethod use:

```
if((bool)e.IsVisible)
{
   // It became visible
}
else
{
  // It became hidden
}
```

This works with opening a new Window instance, **this.Show()**, **this.hide()**, **this.Close()**