# Displaying modal login dialog

Tags: c#, wpf, mvvm

I'm trying to display a modal login dialog after the `MainWindow` has been shown. (Like in SSMS)

I know this is not the MVVM approach but I'm using `MainWindow`'s `Loaded` event where I call following code:

```
private void MainWindow_OnLoaded(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
    ViewModel.ShowLoginDialog();
}
```

In the ViewModel I'm calling:

```
public void ShowLoginDialog()
{
    var vm = new LoginControlViewModel();
    var window = new LoginWindow(vm);
    window.ShowDialog();
}
```

Well the login dialog is shown, but the `MainWindow` only get's shown if the Dialog has been closed.

How do I display the `MainWindow` and the LoginDialog at the same time?

Comment: `Loaded` event occurs *before* window is shown. You could use to example [this](http://stackoverflow.com/a/14605461/1997232) answer solution to display something *after* window is rendered and for the first time only.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You call dialog in constructor.If you use MVVM, I suggest you to use IDialogService. You can find it in many MVVM frameworks/libs or write your own easily. Also your problem is solved by this way.

Comment: Do you have an example of a custom DialogService? I've found http://uxprogramming.blogspot.de/2013/06/simple-mvvm-dialogservice.html  but it's throwing an `InvalidOperationException` because the owner window has not been shown yet.